# Best fit design pattern for Conway's Game of life

Tags: java, design-patterns, conways-game-of-life

I am writing a Java program for GOL and wondering which design pattern will be a best fit. I am considering to use State Pattern as it allows objects to alter their behavior based on their state. What do you think?

P.S Where should I ask subjective questions?

**EDIT:** Its a separate question whether you should design pattern or not in GOL, I am wondering if you decide to use one, which one will you choose?

Comment: There are rules in Game Of Life. U need to use Factory pattern to create these rules for you dynamically

Comment: Thanks @Rockstart I will give it a try, I am looking for these kind of suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

The GOL is an extremely simple program.

I am not sure what you imagine by applying a [design pattern](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~tarr/dp/lectures/StateStrategy.pdf) .

In a primitive implementation, your game state should be stored as a 2D array or vector.  It should change on each iteration of a for loop or in response to a user. Your cells should not be classes.

Comment: Well, simple to implement the slow way, anyway .. but yes, one should likely not have to think about a "design pattern" here, so +1 ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but if you have to choose design pattern for GOL, which one would you choose?

Comment: @RaviGupta Its not clear what part you want to apply this 'design pattern' to. The GOL is a procedural program and none of these GUI interaction styles are relent words when we talk about the GOL. Simply put, your question makes no sense.

Comment: For instance, you could say that there can be only one instance of Board or Universe, isn't it a use case for singleton pattern?

Comment: @Misha: Why should not be the elements of the matrix be classes?

Comment: @Rockstart The only 'state' that the cells have is a boolean status. There already exists a way to have a boolean status - by having a boolean (or an int). Things like the grid can be classes, but it will slow your code down and waste your time to implement a primitive as a class, and your peers will make fun of you.

Comment: @Misha: What if there is a new rule in the game saying that , those cells who survive more than 3 generations continuously should die? Where do you store this information?

Comment: @Rockstart The 'Java' way is to overwrite the function that performs the check and hope that JIT in-lines it. The idea here is that the instances represent the state and the functions represent how they interact. In my mind there are different grids, with different rules, and the grid class is abstract, so that you have to implement those rules. Although now we are moving into subjective territory. The truth is that design pattern discussion seems like a distraction for the task at hand.